# php 5.6 - connecting at oracle DB using pdo and specify charset/encoding

Tags: php, pdo

I'm not sure what i could be missing, but currently with this working code I'm able to connect, query and return the results from the db table properly.

But how could show the results from the table with the correct encoding? since special chars like ç, á  are being displayed sometimes like question mark or a square box.

Bellow, all the information that i have so far, but I believe definition must be set on the PDO because if i simply do an `echo "ç -á";` on the page, the chars will be displayed properly.

**Oracle 11 Table charset:**

Query: `SELECT value$ FROM sys.props$ WHERE name = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET' ;`

Result: `WE8MSWIN1252`

**php.ini file encoding settings:**

```
default_charset = "UTF-8"
internal_encoding = "UTF-8"
input_encoding = "UTF-8"
output_encoding = "UTF-8"
```

**Code example:**

```
#
# PDO Connect example
#
$tns           = "
(DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA=
        (SID=the_database)
    )
)
";
$username = "x";
$password = "x";
try {
    $conn = new PDO("oci:dbname=" . $tns, $username, $password );
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

#
# Fetch results and build html table
#
$sql = "select * table";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
echo '<table>';
echo '<thead>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>Info</th>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '</thead>';
echo '<tbody>';
foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td >' . $row['INFO'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</tbody>';
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Looks like your table charset is Windows 1252 (basically Latin 8859-1); you need your tables to use UTF8 as well.

Comment: @CD001 I believe i need to change the php side, since changing the charset of the table isn't allowed. So, i'll try to update the php side to latin to see if it will works. I'm not sure if this is the right direction, could you please elaborate so i can understand better? =)

Comment: That should work - you pretty much want to follow the advice here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through/279279 ... but switch everything to `ISO-8859-1` (Windows 1252 is a subset of that so it should be fine).

Comment: Have you ever solved this problem??

Comment: @KaKa Sadly I don't have the environment to test this anymore, but the good news is, I had the approval to migrate the whole solution to Django. so the previous solution was discontinued.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `:charset=utf8` to the end of your DSN string should result in:

- the database session being created with UTF-8 as the session encoding
- the data is stored as Windows-1252, based on that NLS WE8MSWIN1252 setting
- Oracle will try to convert the raw Windows-1252 value in the column into an equivalent UTF-8 string as requested by your database session's UTF-8 setting
- *if and only if* that raw Windows-1252 raw byte value correctly matches a valid UTF-8 character (which I'm pretty sure all 1252 chars have valid UTF-8 matches), then the value returned should be visible to you as the UTF-8 character

Since you said that a raw `echo` of those special characters does appear correctly in your browser, then most likely your "viewer" settings (browser) are such that echoing the returned UTF-8 characters should succeed.